# How is the product of abstract affine varieties defined?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, affine-varieties

I'm studying Algebraic Geometry from [Gathmann's Notes](https://agag-gathmann.math.rptu.de/class/alggeom-2021/alggeom-2021.pdf) and I don't find really satisfying how the product of abstract affine varieties is defined.

> **Page 34 (Gathmann's Notes)**
> "[...] products involving X can be defined using any embedding of X in
> affine space (yielding a product that is unique up to isomorphisms)."

Does this mean that there is no canonical way of defining such product and I have to accept it as a definition up to isomorphism?

Comment: The product is perfectly well-defined, but if you define affine varieties through embeddings in affine space, then it makes sense that constructing the product will use those embeddings, and then you have to show that it does not depend on the choice. But if you define varieties intrinsically, then the product can be defined intrinsically as well.

Comment: And how is it defined intrinsically?

Comment: @Kandinskij as an affine scheme, a spectrum of a nice enough algebra, and then the product of varieties is the spectrum of the tensor product of algebras.